# How can I modify the proxied path in a Kubernetes NGINX Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass https://externaldomain.com/api/;
}
```

without passing nginx a server-snippet, through the spec instead.

So if a request hits `https://myingress.com/endpoint`, my cluster serves them the content from `https://externaldomain.com/api/endpoint`

I have an `ExternalName` service set up:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-proxy
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: externaldomain.com
```

And an Ingress path to reach it, but without the path change:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "externaldomain.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_ssl_name externaldomain.com;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myingress.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: api-proxy
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation setting `proxy_redirect` annotations should do the trick: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-redirect

Comment: The documentation didn't seem very clear to me that it would have the desired effect, but indeed it did. I overlooked it entirely. Thank you so much!